# How can i add days to current date in laravel using js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to add number of days like 2,3,4 to current date of another data in laravel

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: Please can you at least show the code you have so far?

Comment: public function store(Request $request){
         $vaccines = VaccinationInfo::create([
           'vaccination_name' => request('vaccination_name'),
           'purpose' => request('purpose'),
           'actual_date' => request('actual_date'),
           'vaccination_date' => request('vaccination_date'),
           'remark' => request('remark'),
           'status' =>request('status'),
        ]);
        return redirect()->route(('vaccination.index'),compact('vaccines'))->with('flash_message_success','Inforamtion added successfully');
    }

Comment: this is the controller and if i add actual date of first vaccine say 14th feb and its vaccination date is after actual date say 16th feb then the second vaccination actual date must be the vaccination taken date of first vaccine + second vaccination actual date .Its like second vaccination actual date must be (no. of days exceed of first vaccination date from its actual date + second vaccination actual date)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean add add number of days to current today date you can use
carbon

```
$num=4;
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays($num);
```